# Have a Thread wait for a Condition

Tags: java, multithreading

In a GUI, I have a few buttons.  These buttons spin off worker threads that send requests over the network to a server.  In a seperate thread, there is a listener that receives the responses from the server.  This response is passed to the same object that the worker threads are executing methods on via the Observer/Observable interface.

What I need to do is to have the worker threads wait for a response from the server that pertains to them.  Essentially a worker thread should send the command, then wait for some condition that indicates the right response was received.  I can think of multiple ways to do this (sleeping, polling, wait, notify, monitors, etc), but is there a particular method that would be best in this situation?

Comment: What's wrong with just waiting for response (like socketInputStream.read()), until you get full response and then acting on it? That's what worker threads are for. Why do you have extra thread for listening for responses? To your question ... wait (on worker thread)/notify (observing thread) should work fine.

Comment: I can't do just a read because I have a seperate thread managing the socket.  That seperate thread is needed because the server may send back responses when I'm not waiting for one.  For example, the server may send a "response" that it is shutting down.  Without that listening thread my client/GUI would not be notified until it tries to interact with the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend to use a high level "locking" mechanism from the [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package
Eg a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) -- "A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes. "

Comment: I was looking at the CountDownLatch before, but that seemed like it was more geared for multiple threads.  For now though, I believe that will work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like a place you want to block at all.  You are already in a worker thread so you aren't holding any kind of state for your GUI or anything, I'd send the message and bail--when your response comes back, grab another thread out of the pool and send it on it's merry way.

If you have data that is shared between the two, put it into its own object in a collection keyed by some common value and have the new thread pull it out when it comes in.

For readability/simplicity make the object with the data also contain the code that knows how to handle that data so that all you have to do when you get an incoming message is retrieve a key that uniquely identifies which object sent it, retrieve that object by the key and call that object's "Data received" method passing in the information you got from the packet.

The nice thing about this is it makes it trivial for a simple listener to handle a huge variety of incoming packets by making the "Data received" method an interface that many different handlers can implement.

OO is cool, eh?

Comment: Hi Bill,  that method does make a lot of sense.  Right now though, my program is setup so a call to "getData()" actually returns the data.  But since the rest of the project is becoming more defined, I may transition to this approach since I can know exactly what to update when a particular request comes in.  Thanks!